# Como pegar o retorno deste metodo

Tags: android, orientação-a-objetos

Estou utilizando a lib **betterpickers**, tentei fazer uma classe para pegar sua informação de forma OO, porem o método não tem um retorno, ele é um void, existe uma maneira de pegar esse retorno?

```
public class Inflate implements CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener{

private static final String FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER = "fragment_date_picker_name";

public void piker(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager){
    CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
            .setOnDateSetListener(this);
    cdp.show(supportFragmentManager, FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
   //Esse é o metodo
}
}
```

Eu o chamo na MainActivity assim:

```
   Inflate inflate = new Inflate();

   tes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           inflate.piker(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
    });
```

Eu já tentei algo como onDateSet chamar outro método:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    getData(year + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth);
}

public String getData(String data){
    return data;
}
```

Porem, como eu pegaria esse retorno se eu estou chamando o piker? Esse é o problema, existe alguma maneira de o fazer? Porque nessa activity tenho 4 lugares onde deve ser definido uma data, se para cada um eu tiver que fazer um método diferente o código fica enorme.

Documentação: https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

Comment: Posta a documentação para vermos.

Comment: @RBZ pronto, adicionei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente consegui, eu mudei o método e a classe, ficou assim:

```
public class Inflate{

    private static final String FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER = "fragment_date_picker_name";

    public void piker(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, final TextView textView){
        CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment();
                cdp.setOnDateSetListener(new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        String data = year + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth;                 //Após setar a data eu chamo o método na MainActivity para passar a data para o TextView
                        MainActivity.setData(data, textView);
                    }
                });

        cdp.show(supportFragmentManager, FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
    }
}
```

Eu o chamo assim agora:

```
Inflate inflate = new Inflate();
tes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //Agora além do FragmentManager, também passo o TextView que irá receber o valor.

               inflate.piker(getSupportFragmentManager(), tes);
            }
 });
```

Na MainActivity, este é o método chamado após setar a data, ele recebe a data em String e o TextView que irá receber o valor:

```
public static void setData(String data, TextView textView) {
       //Então é só setar a data
        textView.setText(data);
}
```